# Connecting to Oracle from Excel

Tags: oracle, excel, vba

I need to call an SQL request on an Oracle database from an Excel Sub. Here is the VB code I'm using to connect:

```
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    With cn
        .Provider = "MSDAORA.1"
        .Properties("Data source") = "INSTANCENAME"
        .Properties("User Id") = "USER"
        .Properties("Password") = "PWD123"
        .Open
    End With
```

When I call it from a 32-bits Excell to a 32-bits Oracle client, it works well. But the target is a 32-bits Excel and a 64-bit Oracle client (I can't change this config). In this case I get the following error:

> Oracle client and networking components were not found. These components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the Oracle Version 7.3.3 or later client software installation. Provider is unable to function until these components are installed.

Is it possible to call a 64-bit Oracle client from a 32-bits Excel using the same component or should I use another driver?

Any other idea is welcome.

**EDIT** : I can't install another Oracle client, so I can't use ODBC

Comment: ODBC should work

Comment: ODBC works for sure, but an Oracle ODBC driver has to be registered first in Windows. That might be a problem for OP if he does not have Windows admin rights.

Comment: I have found that with Excel, if Excel is 32 bits, the client must be 32 bits. I just went through this myself, and could not find a single reference that said otherwise. I truly hope someone finds something different as it would greatly simplify my life.